# How to configure crontab file....?

Tags: linux

I am new for configuring crontab file. can anyone explain to me how to add Job in crontab file. similarly after adding job how to run this file. quick Response would be appreciate.

Ex: 40 10 * * * rm/home/test/tmp*/

I am trying run this through editing crontab -e but i am unable to delete tmp directory files..

Comment: The entry you added only executes the command at 10:40 AM, is this the problem?

Comment: No dear any time no problem actually it is not executing

Answer (score 2):

- There is a space after the `rm` command, and the asterisk to specify all files is after the slash in a path (`rm /home/test/tmp/*`, not `rm/home/test/tmp*/`), so make sure the command is entered properly in the crontab
- Be sure to save when exiting from the editor after opening it using `sudo crontab -e`. It should automatically run at the next scheduled time provided the `cron` service is running (which is started at boot)

Comment: I have done it as you mention above still i am unable to delete /tmp directory files.

Comment: Dear Brother i am completely new for linux i don't know how to configure corntab file can you plz explain to me from the beginning how to add jobs in crontab file and how to execute  crontab file.